# Badge Notification shows up after reinstalling ionic app on IOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am using ionic framework and I am showing badge notifications following this article 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge/

I first installed the app (in IOS), calculated badges and closed the app. Now badges are still there on app icon. Now when I delete the app and reinstalled it, same number of badges are showing up, over the icon. I don't want this thing to happen.

I have read that it takes 1 day to get the app data cleaned up after deletion.

**I have followed many solutions to remove device memory for the app when we delete it, this is from within the ios device, but I need a solution from coding perspective. Is there any way I can add some thing on config.xml or install any package that remove app data instantly when we delete the app in IOS?**

I have following these articles, but nothing working.

[ionic set badge after push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744471/ionic-set-badge-after-push-notification)

[iOS reinstalling app does not clear badges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700783/ios-reinstalling-app-does-not-clear-badges)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: Did you find the solution for these ? I am facing similar issue in ionic app using same badge plugin

Answer (score 1):

there's a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge) which handles badge staus on app icon.

**Cordova Badge Plugin**

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.clear();
```

hope you'd get a hint from this plugin. thanks

Comment: I am facing same issue and there is no solution I am getting from ionic team and cordova team
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge/issues/135 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge/issues/134